# Bash 'read' command requires many 'enters' before returning

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script along the lines of the following:

```bsh
long_command --some --arguments
long_command_2 --other --arguments
...

echo -e "\nSet up next step, then press enter to continue..."
read -p ""

another_long_command --some --arguments
```

I'm expecting that a single "Enter" on the read command would immediately start the following command. However, I've noticed I have tap "Enter" quite a few times (~ 10 times or so), before the next command is executed.

I'm wondering what could be going on? Is `stdin` being eaten by the old command? Some odd buffering behavior going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your before-`read` processes are still running, then they could consume `stdin`. Equally it's possible that the after-`read` processes take some time to startup and output anything (i.e: try pressing return once and waiting).

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you provide an example that is [complete and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? ([edit] the question). From your current code I can run only `echo` and `read`, they are completely fine by themselves. How do you know `another_long_command` is not executed? Maybe it needs some time before printing anything? Or maybe it needs 9 lines of input?

Comment: Thanks so much for the comments and sorry for the delay!

Comment: @Attie: It is definitely possible the previous commands start a child process. Would an easy way to check be to run `ps --ppid <pid of the bash>`? Can child non-foreground processes consume `stdin` though?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Gotcha, unfortunately the commands I'm running are more custom (a lot going on in them). I can confirm that the `another_long_command` shouldn't need any stdin to start, but let me substitute that command with `echo` and see if the behavior is reproducible.

Comment: @JeffN - if your processes don't need `stdin`, then you can give them `/dev/null` explicitly: `long_command --some --arguments </dev/null`